# How to group items under specific parent item in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `groups` API which has `id` and `group_name` field. There is another `training` API which gives me `training_name` and `training_group_id`.
Every training in `training` API is linked to a group.

Present Output on UI -
**Group 1** -
Training 1 |
**Group 2** -
Training 2 |
**Group 2** -
Training 3 |
**Group 2** -
Training 4

Is there a way I can show by grouping the trainings which has common `group_name` to appear under one `group_name` and not repeat as shown in above output?

Expected Output on UI -
**Group 1** -
Training 1 |
**Group 2** -
Training 2, Training 3, Training 4

Code -

```
function TileViewNew() {
  const { currentUserTrainings, trainingGroups } = useContext(MyContext);

  const renderTrainingGroupName = training => {
    const trainingGroupName = trainingGroups.find(group => {
      return group.id === training;
    });
    return trainingGroupName.group_name;
  };

  return (
    <Grid>
      {currentUserTrainings.map(({ training_name, training_group }) => (
        <>
          <Grid>
            <strong>{renderTrainingGroupName(training_group)}</strong>
          </Grid>
          {training_name}
        </>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default TileViewNew;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to construct a new data structure
to achieve the rendering you want
Because UI = fn(data)
I hope this helps you
[image]

```js
import { type FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const currentUserTrainings = [
    {
        training_name: 'Training 1',
        training_group: 1,
    },
    {
        training_name: 'Training 2',
        training_group: 2,
    },
    {
        training_name: 'Training 3',
        training_group: 2,
    },
    {
        training_name: 'Training 4',
        training_group: 2,
    },
];
const trainingGroups = [
    {
        group_name: 'Group 1',
        group_id: 1,
    },
    {
        group_name: 'Group 2',
        group_id: 2,
    },
];

export const TileViewNew: FC = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const targetDate = currentUserTrainings.map((item) => {
            const group = trainingGroups.find((group) => group.group_id === item.training_group);
            return {
                ...item,
                group_name: group.group_name,
            };
        });

        const targetResult = {};
        targetDate.forEach((item) => {
            targetResult[item.group_name] = targetResult[item.group_name] || [];
            targetResult[item.group_name].push(item);
        });
        // console.log(targetResult);
        setResult(targetResult);
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            {Object.keys(result).map((k) => (
                <div key={k}>
                    <b>{k}</b>
                    {result[k].map((c) => (
                        <span key={c.training_name}>{c.training_name}</span>
                    ))}
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default TileViewNew;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can basically transform the data you get from api in this fashion

```js
const currentUserTrainings = [{training_name: 'Training 1',training_group_id: 1,},{training_name: 'Training 2',training_group_id: 2,},{training_name: 'Training 3',training_group_id: 2,},{training_name: 'Training 4',training_group_id: 2,},];
const trainingGroups = [{group_name: 'Group 1',group_id: 1,},{group_name: 'Group 2',group_id: 2,},];

// group trainings by group id

let transformedTraining = currentUserTrainings.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  let id = curr.training_group_id
  acc[id] = acc[id] || []
  acc[id].push(curr)
  return acc
}, {})

// loop over groups to show final output

trainingGroups.forEach((curr)=>{
  let name = curr.group_name
  let id  = curr.group_id
  let trainings = transformedTraining[id]?.map(v => v.training_name).join(',')
  console.log(name, trainings)
})
```